# rar command line for creating .zip files

Tags: command-line, zip, rar

Is there a way to use the rar command line to create .zip files?

Comment: Do you mean to do this from a pyogram?

Comment: As an alternative you can use Info-ZIP or 7-zip. What platform are you on?

Answer (score 3):

No, the command-line version does not support the zip format.

Source: http://www.win-rar.com/index.php?id=24&kb=1&kb_article_id=64

There are other command-line tools to create zip archives, though. For instance, check out http://www.info-zip.org